# Adding a Scrollbar to a CustomScollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been trying to figure out how to add a Scrollbar Widget to a CustomScrollView.
One would usually just have to wrap a ListView or ScrollView with a Scrollbar Widget, pass in the same ScrollController and boom, it's rendered.

Here is a minimal code block.

```
CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                title: Hero(
                  tag: 'title',
                  child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                          text: 'Not',
                          style: TextStyle( fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        TextSpan(
                          text: '3s',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) {
                    return Container(); })));
```

Comment: Interesting. I've also tried wrapping CustomScrollView with a [Scrollbar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html), but the Scrollbar isn't rendered. Documentation shows that it should be possible to add a scrollbar to a ScrollView by wrapping the ScrollView widget in a Scrollbar widget.

Comment: Exactly. A CustomScrollView is also built upon a ScrollView, so it is meant to render as. I will dig around the source code of the CustomScrollView and see what I can find.

Answer (score 6):

I got it.

Create a _scrollController.

Wrap the CustomScrollView() in a ScrollBar() Widget.

Set the controller: parameter of BOTH CustomerScrollView and ScrollBar as the _scrollController.

```
final _scrollController = ScrollController();
return Scaffold(
  body: Scrollbar(
    controller: _scrollController,
    isAlwaysShown: true,
    child: CustomScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      slivers: <Widget> [
        ...
```

Modify as you need.

Comment: This works - but you have to scroll to make the scrollbar appear in the first place. isAlwaysShown does not show the scrollbar initially.

Comment: Set the thickness - mine shows when I use thickness: 5

Comment: Still not seeing the scrollbar initially - I have to scroll for it to show in the first place...